# What is the correct way to modify Page from an EventHandler in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, eventhandler

Take this example:

I have a Web Form that consists of Test.aspx and Test.aspx.cs.

My Page_Load function binds the event handler "EventHappensCompleted" to an event that happens with the object "myThing" along with doing some writes to the web page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_Load");
    try
    {
        var myThing = new MyThing();
        myThing.EventHappens += EventHappensCompleted;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Response.Write("ERROR");
    }
}
```

My "EventHappensCompleted" function looks like this:

```
protected void EventHappensCompleted(object o, CustomEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("EventHappensCompleted");
}
```

When I first load the page, I'll see "Page_Load" written to the page.  When the first event happens, I'll see "EventHappensCompleted" written to the page, but any events after that will not get written to the page.

I think this behavior has something to do with the subsequent Event Handlers being on different threads and not being able to access the right context in order to write to the page, but I'm not sure.

How can I modify this code so that the Event Handler will write to the page every time?

EDIT 1: I should make it clear that the subsequent events are, in fact, happening.  The issue is not that the events aren't actually happening.

EDIT 2: Here is the full Test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Page_Load");
        try
        {
            var myThing = new MyThing();
            myThing.EventHappens += EventHappensCompleted;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Response.Write("ERROR");
        }
    }

    protected void EventHappensCompleted(object o, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("EventHappensCompleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you're saying events aren't being written to the page. Then you're saying they're happening? What's the desired behaviour?

Comment: Correct.  The "Response.Write" commands aren't outputting to the page for any event after the first one.

The events themselves are happening and firing the EventHandler as expected (I can confirm this by outputting to the debug log with "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine").

Desired behavior is having Response.Write("EventHappensCompleted") output to the page everytime it is fired from the EventHandler instead of only the first.

Comment: So subsequent button presses still show a single line "EventsHappensCompleted"? As that's what's supposed to happen, you're writing a single line in the response. The previous response will have cleared

Comment: Sean, this was the issue.  I was expecting the Response.Write inside the EventHandler to append text to the page like the other.  Instead it was replacing what it output after the first time.  Can you give an explanation as to why this is?  Also, if you submit this as an answer I'll mark this post as answered.

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation and a solution

Comment: If you're learning ASP.NET for the first time, [don't start with Web Forms](http://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/stop-using-aspnet-webforms) (my own blog entry). There's far better frameworks for you to learn that are easier to work with, will be better for your career, and better for your end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is firing and the response is getting written to the page. The previous response will not be present so it will appear that the event has not fired.

This is because when using webforms the entire page is recreated in the response. So your previous response no longer exists. It's worth reading up on ViewState in webforms, if you want to get around this you can use AJAX or a client side event that adds to the page without redrawing the entire html content.

To get around this, you could implement a count or something like so...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (ViewState["counter"] != null)
        {
            int counter = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["counter"]);

            ViewState["counter"] = counter++;
        }        
        else
        {
            int count = 1;

            ViewState["counter"] = count;
        }   

        var myThing = new MyThing();
        myThing.EventHappens += EventHappensCompleted;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Response.Write("ERROR");
    }
}
```

And the event..

```
protected void EventHappensCompleted(object o, CustomEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["counter"] != null)
    {
        var count = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["counter"]);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write("EventHappensCompleted");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same behavior.

MyThing is just an imaginary placeholder class.

Comment: What's your actual code. Becuase what I've posted will fire each time. Do you have it wrapped in a `if(!Postback)` or something?

Comment: What's your code?  I've edited my post to include the full Test.aspx.cs.